# Escolher quais itens de um enumerador aparecer em um EnumDropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Há como selecionar apenas alguns itens do enumerador para enviar para um `EnumDropDownListFor` ?

Por ex:

```
public enum Documento
{
   CPF = 1,
   RG = 2,
   CNPJ= 3
   NASCIMENTO = 4
}
```

E gostaria que em uma determinada `View`, no `EnumDropDownListFor` fosse informado apenas os 2 primeiros, em outra `View`, os 2 últimos, em outra os 2 do meio, ou seja, que eu possa escolher de alguma forma quais itens irá aparecer no `EnumDropDownList`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pra este caso não acho produtivo usar `EnumDropDownListFor`. Acho melhor usar o `DropDownListFor` e definir toda a lógica dentro:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Documento, 
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Documento)).OfType<Documento>()
        .Where(/* Coloque a condição de filtro aqui */)
        .Select(option => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = option.Literal(),
            Value = option.ToString(),
            Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Documento == option)
        }), "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Para exibir os textos corretamente com acentos, uso um arquivo de *Resource* (no exemplo abaixo, `Linguagem.resx`) e um método de extensão, a seguir:

```
public static class EnumsExtensions
{
    public static String Literal(this Enum e)
    {
        return Linguagem.ResourceManager.GetString(e.ToString());
    }
}
```