# DropDownList com dados de um Enum

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-helper

Preciso fazer um Helper onde eu passo um Enum e ele monta um DropDownList baseado em todos os valores do Enum, eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

C#:

```
public static HtmlString DropDownListEnumFor(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Type _enum, string name, int value)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = string.Empty,
                Value = string.Empty
            });

            //percorre objetos do enum
            foreach (var item in (_enum).GetFields())
            {
                if (item.FieldType == (_enum))
                {
                    //busca atributos definidos
                    var e = item.GetValue(item);
                    var nome = AttributesHelper.DescricaoEnum(e);

                    //carrega list de retorno
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome))
                    {
                        lst.Add(new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Text = nome,
                            Value = ((int)item.GetValue(item)).ToString(),
                            Selected = value == e.GetHashCode()
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
            MvcHtmlString html = htmlHelper.DropDownList(name, lst, new object { });

            return html;
        }


public static T Convert<T>(object value)
    {
        var output = value.ToString();

        var member = value.GetType().GetMember(output).First();
        var attributes = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);

        T obj = attributes.Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault();

        return obj;
    }


public static string DescricaoEnum(object obj)
    {
        return Convert<DescriptionAttribute>(obj).Description;
    }
```

Html:

```
@Html.DropDownListEnumFor(typeof(TipoObjetoEnum), "ddlTeste", 1)
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de eu passar um tipo de Enum para a minha classe e conseguir fazer o que foi mencionado?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Escolher quais itens de um enumerador aparecer em um EnumDropDownListFor](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95375/escolher-quais-itens-de-um-enumerador-aparecer-em-um-enumdropdownlistfor)

Comment: São perguntas completamente diferentes... São é só porque trata sobre o mesmo assunto que é considerada duplicata. Eu sei como montar o DropDownList baseado nos dados do Enum, o que eu quero é passar o tipo do Enum para um método externo a minha View e com isso pegar os dados do Enum.

Comment: **Qual seria a melhor forma de eu passar um tipo de Enum para a minha classe e conseguir fazer o que foi mencionado?** Acho que a resposta daquela pergunta responde a sua pergunta. Basta não usar o `.Where` e pronto.

Comment: Caro, analise o código da pergunta. São propostas diferentes... Eu não quero montar o `SelectListItem` na View com os dados do `Enum` eu quero passar o `TEnum` para a minha classe do Helper e ela ser responsável por me retornar a HtmlString do dropdown.

Comment: Isso não ficou claro na pergunta. Quando você pediu "a melhor forma", achei que não queria arrumar o que já possui, e sim "uma forma melhor". Bom, vamos resolver seu problema então. Qual o problema da forma que está? Poderia postar o `AttributesHelper.DescricaoEnum();`?

Comment: Adicionei os métodos que faltavam na pergunta.

Comment: Eu queria entender o objetivo disso. Por que você faz questão de montar a *DropDown* dentro de uma *Extension*?

Comment: O fato de a minha aplicação ter a utilização de Enuns em DropDowns em vários locais me fez pensar nesse tipo de solução, para não ter que ficar replicando código em todas as Controllers, onde tem que sempre criar uma ViewBag para passar o SelectList pra View. então achei que seria melhor criar um Helper

Comment: Faltou dizer qual o problema. Testei seu código e está funcionando normalmente? O que você realmente deseja?