# Carregar um Dropdownlist com base em um enum - Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um enum PessoaNatureza que se relaciona com a tabela Pessoa. Preciso criar um dropdownlist na minha view que exiba a lista de PessoasNaturezas (PESSOA FÍSICA E PESSOA JURÍDICA), inclusive mostrando a pessoanatureza relacionada ao atual registro, de acordo com a viewmodel. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

PessoaNatureza

```
 public enum PessoaNatureza
 {
     [Description("FÍSICA")]
     Fisica = 1,
     [Description("JURÍDICA")]
     Juridica = 2
 }
```

PessoaViewModel

```
 public class PessoaViewModel
 {
     [Key]
     [DisplayName("Código")]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [DisplayName("Natureza")]
     [Display(Name = "Natureza")]
     [RegularExpression(@"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma Natureza de Pessoa")]
     public int PessoaNaturezaId { get; set; }
     public List<SelectListItem> PessoasNaturezas { get; set; }
  }
```

Edit.cshtml

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="PessoaNaturezaId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <input asp-for="PessoaNaturezaId" class="form-control" />
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PessoaNaturezaId, Model.PessoaNatureza, "--Selecione--", new { @class = "form-control" })
          <span asp-validation-for="PessoaNaturezaId" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953/how-do-you-bind-an-enum-to-a-dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net

Comment: outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95375/escolher-quais-itens-de-um-enumerador-aparecer-em-um-enumdropdownlistfor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe `static` e manipular seu `Enum` para popular seu `SelectListItem`

```
public static class ExtensaoDeEnumerador
{
    public static string GetEnumDescription<T>(string value)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var name = Enum.GetNames(type).Where(f => f.Equals(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(d => d).FirstOrDefault();

        if (name == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var field = type.GetField(name);
        var customAttribute = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        return customAttribute.Length > 0 ? ((DescriptionAttribute)customAttribute[0]).Description : name;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EnumToSelectList<T>(string tipoCase = null)
    {
        return (Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Select(
            e => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = (tipoCase == null ? GetEnumDescription<T>(e.ToString()) : (tipoCase.ToUpper() == "U" ? GetEnumDescription<T>(e.ToString()).ToUpper() : GetEnumDescription<T>(e.ToString()).ToLower())),
                Value = e.ToString()
            })).ToList();
    }
}
```

Veja a chamada.

```
pessoaViewModel.PessoasNaturezas = ExtensaoDeEnumerador.EnumToSelectList<PessoaNatureza>("U").OrderBy(x => x.Text);
```

Comment: Marconcilio, a parte de carregar o dropdownlist funcionou, só que quando ele abre o registro, ele não dá o binding para relacionar o tipo de pessoa correto... O que devo fazer?

Comment: você tem que dizer qual é ele..                 pessoaViewModel.PessoasNaturezas.Where(x => x.Value.Equals(pessoaViewModel.PessoasNatureza.ToString())).FirstOrDefault().Selected = true;

Answer (score 1):

Segue outra opção, embora eu prefira a abordagem do Marconcilio, por resolver a funcionalidade como um todo e não apenas essa questão pontual. Mas também não concordo muito a estrutura apresentada na pergunta.

Você pode adicionar um construtor para sua ViewModel onde você popula a `List<SelectListItem> PessoasNaturezas` com os valores do Enum e marca como selecionado o valor populado na `PessoaNaturezaId`.

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Código")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
    [Display(Name = "Natureza")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma Natureza de Pessoa")]
    public int PessoaNaturezaId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PessoasNaturezas { get; set; }

    public PessoaViewModel()
    {
        var listaPessoaNatureza = from PessoaNatureza pn in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PessoaNatureza))
                                  select new SelectListItem
                                  {
                                      Value = ((int)pn).ToString(),
                                      Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(PessoaNatureza), pn),
                                      Selected = PessoaNaturezaId == (int)pn ? true : false
                                  };
        PessoasNaturezas = listaPessoaNatureza.ToList();
    }
}
```

E na sua view você pode manter o padrão de helpers utilizando o `<select asp-for..`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="PessoaNaturezaId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <select asp-for="PessoaNaturezaId" asp-items="Model.PessoasNaturezas">
            <option value="">--Selecione--</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="PessoaNaturezaId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Isso "resolve" o seu problema, mas recomendo que opte pela solução apresentada pelo colega. Só recomendo a minha proposta, caso tenha dificuldades em entender ou implementar a outra sugestão.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição Leandro!

Comment: Leandro, estou tentando criar uma função generica para setar a propriedade Selected para ele fazer o binding corretamente... Só que o enum é genérico <T>... como eu seto ele???

Comment: public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EnumToSelectList<T>(string tipoCase = null, string selected = null)
        {
            return (Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Select(
                e => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = (tipoCase == null ? GetEnumDescription<T>(e.ToString()) : (tipoCase.ToUpper() == "U" ? GetEnumDescription<T>(e.ToString()).ToUpper() : GetEnumDescription<T>(e.ToString()).ToLower())),
                    Value = e.ToString(),
                    Selected = ???????????????????????
                })).ToList();
        }

Comment: @JalberRomano, Essa seria outra pergunta... mas no caso da outra resposta a identificação do selected ficaria na View ou em um loop na Controller. Ou você cria um overload recebendo esse parâmetro e implementa na ExtensaoDeEnumerador. (Como eu disse antes, deixei a minha resposta para caso você encontrasse dificuldades com a outra)

Comment: Eu carrego minha viewmodel na camada Application, na classe PessoaAppService, para ser mais exato. No meu método getById, eu seto tudo lá e aproveito para chamar a classe ExtensaoDeEnumerador, carregar o Dropdownlist e setar a propriedade "Selected" com o PessoaNaturezaId... Eu estava tendo dificuldades em setá-lo, pois meu enum estava indo como 1 e lá na classe, na hora de comparar, a variável estava como "fisica".... "1" é diferente de "fisica". Eu alterei e funcionou 100%

Comment: De todas as formas, sou grato por sua ajuda e tb ao @Marconcilio!!!

Comment: estou com um erro aqui.. asp-items="Model.Categorias". Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo . sabe  o que posso fazer?